# Find string between HTML tags

Tags: regex

I have a HTML text:

```
<p class=MsoBodyText>Becky Handler</p>
```

How to find String between open an close tags except tags?
I try `(>[^>]*<)` or `(>\s*\w.*?<)` and result is `>Becky Handler<`

Comment: Are you using javascript or jQuery for this?

Comment: if it is javacript and jquery it is easier , can be done without regex. Kindly mentioni which language, you working

Comment: @AmitJoki, the tool is top secret, look at comments in other questions :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*If you're using regex in context of a programming language*:
put `>` and `<` outside of the [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (parentheses), e.g. `>([^<>]*)<` and extract only the contents of the group.

*Alternatively*: use [lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), e.g. `(?<=>)([^<>]*)(?=<)`.

[See fiddle](http://refiddle.co/refiddles/548d9ea675622d09fae90b00).

Note that lookahead/lookbehind is not supported by some regex engines.

Comment: This regex will not account for < inside of text.

Comment: The HTML:<p class=MsoBodyText>Becky Handler</p>
<p class=MsoBodyText>18 Cross Court, Down-the-Line, PA</p>

Comment: @Natan, which tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: @Natan Check my answer, it works for your regex

Comment: @TejasPatel: the character `<` as a literal is not allowed in the text part of an html document.